# How to run x86_64 image on Android Studio emulator in a M1 Mac?

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, qemu, apple-m1

I am trying to find a solution after running into `PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'x86' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on aarch64 host.` and I do not have the option of using a lower version of android.

Would this be possible by installing an intel chip version of Android Studio and running it with Rosetta? I am currently on Monterey.

Comment: Given that Android runs on multiple CPU architectures, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73354637/edit) your post to explain why x86 on Mac M1 as any third-party app library/code should have ARM version.